# Copying entire row to a sheet based on cell Value

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I want to copy the entire row on Sheet1 based on the cell value in column F. I have a the main request sheet labeled "Master Requests" that anyone can access and then I have a dropdown in Column F (starting at row 3) that has different selections "Marketing", "Advertising", "Office Work", etc. The entry data goes from Column A through Column P. Based on the dropdown value in Column F I want the entire row to be copied to the sheet with the same name, i.e., if the value in F4 is "Marketing" then I want to copy the whole row (not delete it) and move it to the sheet named "Marketing" on the same spreadsheet.  And I don't know why I'm having so much trouble!

```
function copyRowsToSpaySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Requests");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Marketing");
  
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][6] == "Marketing") {
      targetSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting the above to work, but it just leaves the sheet blank.

And I tried this as well

```
function moveRows(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Requests');
  const marketSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Marketing');
  const marketLastRow = marketSheet.getLastRow();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let sortRange = sheet.getSheetValues(4,1,lastRow,16);
  Logger.log(lastRow)
  //Logger.log(typeof(sortRange))
  //Logger.log(sortRange.length);
  let marketcounter = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++){
    let name = sheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    console.log(i + " - " + name);
    if (name == "Marketing") {
      let rowValues = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 16)
      marketSheet.getRange(marketLastRow+spaycounter, 1, 1, 16).setValues(rowValues);
      marketcounter++;
    }
    };
  };
```

Which also leaves my sheet named "Marketing" empty.

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is supposed to trigger this code?  Is it a time based trigger?  An edit? A button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

> *Note: @[Codedabbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20635660/codedabbler) is correct that changing `data[i][6]` to `data[i][5]` in the first snippet resolves the issue. This is to provide some other options to execute the script aside from running it in the Google Apps Script Editor.*

The full code corrected would be:

```
function copyRowsToSpaySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Requests");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Marketing");
  var advertising = ss.getSheetByName("Advertising");
  var officeWork = ss.getSheetByName("Office Work");
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][5] == "Marketing") {
      targetSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
    } else if (data[i][5] == "Advertising") {
      advertising.appendRow(data[i]);
    } else if (data[i][5] == "Office Work") {
      officeWork.appendRow(data[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

> This includes the `Advertising` and `Office Work` sheets from the description.

Here are some options to run the code without going to Google Apps Script:

#### OPTION 1

Use [onOpen(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) in creating a custom menu for the script.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Copy Rows', 'copyRowsToSpaySheet')
    .addToUi();
}

function copyRowsToSpaySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Requests");
  var marketing = ss.getSheetByName("Marketing");
  var advertising = ss.getSheetByName("Advertising");
  var officeWork = ss.getSheetByName("Office Work");
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var targetSheet = data[i][5] == "Marketing" ? marketing : data[i][5] == "Advertising" ? advertising : data[i][5] == "Office Work" ? officeWork : null;
    targetSheet ? targetSheet.appendRow(data[i]) : null;
  }
}
```

This creates something like this:

[image]

#### OPTION 2

Use [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to automatically run the script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var source = e.source;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var value = range.getValue();
  var sheet1 = source.getSheetByName("Master Requests");
  var marketing = source.getSheetByName("Marketing");
  var advertising = source.getSheetByName("Advertising");
  var officeWork = source.getSheetByName("Office Work");
  var sheetValues = sheet1.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var targetSheet = col == 6 && value == "Marketing" ? marketing : col == 6 && value == "Advertising" ? advertising : col == 6 && value == "Office Work" ? officeWork : null;
  targetSheet ? targetSheet.appendRow(sheetValues[0]) : null;
}
```

This runs the code whenever an edit is made to `column F` with the values `Marketing`, `Advertising`, and `Office Work`, copying the row to its respective sheet.

Comment: This is great thank you!! Do you know to modify this if the cells in column F are from a dropdown menu with those options? It recognizes it when it is typed, but not when the data in cell F is not from a dropdown.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The `column F` in my test is actually a drop-down menu like this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEzrZ.png).

Comment: The data in my test was selected from a dropdown as well.  Extra spaces can cause this issue...

Answer (score 2):

Change this line `if (data[i][6] == "Marketing")` to `if (data[i][5] == "Marketing")`.

Column index starts at 0, thus Column F would have a column index of 5.

When I changed it and ran the code, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your script:**

```
const sheets = ["Marketing", "Advertising", "Office Work"]
const ss = (name) => {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
}

function copyRowsToSpaySheet() {
  sheets.forEach((sh) => {
    ss("Master Requests").getDataRange().getValues()
      .forEach((row) => {
        if (row[5] == sh) {
          ss(sh).appendRow(row);
        }
      });
  });
}
```